# How to show values based on the user selection in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-select, streamlit

The options for a second multiselect will be changed according to values in a pre-existing data structure.

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st 
        
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[4,6,6],
                  "B":[4,6,9],
                  "C":[1,2,3],
                 }) 
interactive = st.beta_container()    
col1, col2 = st.beta_columns(2)
            
with interactive: 
     all_columns_names= df.columns.tolist()
     with col1:
         option1 = st.multiselect("select column to plot",all_columns_names)
     with col2:
         option2 = st.multiselect("select required value/s to 
            plot",list(set(df.loc[(df.iloc[:,0].isin(option1))][df.columns[1]])))
```

## example:

```
if   option1 = B
then option2 = [4,6,9]

if option1 = [A,C]
then option2 = [4,6,6,1,2,3]
```

Where is the error in the statement in `col1`? How can I get the values of `option2` that are related to the selected `option1`?

Comment: @KristianCanler is this better ?

Comment: If you're getting an error code, please include that, as well. Besides that, the code looks minimal/reproducible now, but the question might use a little more explanation for clarity.

Comment: @user5980666 Say if `option1` is `A`, what's the logic of `option2`?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh if **option1** is **A**   **option2** must includes [4,6,6]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get values of columns by iterating on each column, and appending them into a container.

```py
with interactive:
     with col2:
         vals = set()

         if not isinstance(option1, list):
             option1 = [option1]

         for col in option1:
             vals.update(df[col].values.tolist())

         option2 = st.multiselect("select required value/s to plot", list(vals))
```